# How do I add an identity property to a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I make a migration that changes an existing column so that it is an identity? Meaning, I want that integer column to automatically increment.

Is it something like:

```
add_identity :tablename, [:columnname]
```

It is not a primary key column.

Comment: Not really, that's being done directly in SQL. I want to do this using a migration in rails.  However, from those answers, it sounds like it can't be done that way.

Comment: I'm not aware of another way of doing it.

Comment: What's wrong with putting straight SQL into a migration using `connection.execute(...)`? I do it all the time to get around AR's rather limited understanding of databases.

Comment: The question @Thilo links to had no good answer for PostgreSQL. I believe to have fixed that now.